# How to download files With SVN Client

Tags: windows, download, svn

What is SVN? And how can I download files from SVN?

I have the following link
http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/source/checkout
I don't know how can I download files from here. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVN is short for Subversion.  I believe that the most popular Subversion client for Windows is [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html).  You can then use a context menu in Windows Explorer in a directory of your choice to download the source code from whatever Subversion URL you want, or http://oolongengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ in your case.

Comment: I've voted you up, but be wary of the fact that Google Code may ask for credentials, or want you to use HTTPS. I know Tortoise prompts for credentials, but for a beginner, it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the note!  I'm not too familiar with Google Code either, so that's good to know.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed TortoiseSVN but when I open Internet explorer and right click on the folder, I don't see any command related to TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Just to make sure, you installed the correct version for your architecture, right?  If you have 64-bit Windows, you must use 64-bit TortoiseSVN for the shell extensions to work.  The other thing you might try is see if _Checkout_ is in the _File_ menu in Explorer.  Also, note that you must use _Windows_ Explorer (the file manager), not _Internet_ Explorer (the browser).